# Doctrine2 / transfer Collection element to another Collection

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

Here are 3 entities :

**Entity A**

```
class EntityA
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EntityB", mappedBy="entityA", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $entitiesB;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->entitiesB = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getEntitiesB()
    {
        return $this->entitiesB;
    }

    public function setEntitiesB($entitiesB)
    {
        $this->entitiesB = new ArrayCollection();

        return $this->addEntitiesB($entitiesB);
    }

    public function addEntityB(EntityB $entityB)
    {
        if (!$this->entitiesB->contains($entityB))
        {
            $this->entitiesB->add($entityB);
            $entityB->setEntityA($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function addEntitiesB($entitiesB)
    {
        foreach ($entitiesB as $entityB)
        {
            $this->addEntityB($entityB);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEntityB(EntityB $entityB)
    {
        if ($this->entitiesB->contains($entityB))
        {
            $this->entitiesB->removeElement($entityB);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEntitiesB($entitiesB)
    {
        foreach ($entitiesB as $entityB)
        {
            $this->removeEntityB($entityB);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Entity B**

```
class EntityB
{
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EntityC", mappedBy="entityB", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $entitiesC;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityA", inversedBy="entitiesB")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_a_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $entityA;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->entitiesC = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getEntityA()
    {
        return $this->entityA;
    }

    public function setEntityA(EntityA $entityA)
    {
        $this->entityA = $entityA;
        $entityA->addEntityB($this);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEntitiesC()
    {
        return $this->entitiesC;
    }

    public function setEntitiesC($entitiesC)
    {
        $this->entitiesC = new ArrayCollection();

        return $this->addEntitiesC($entitiesC);
    }

    public function addEntityC(EntityC $entityC)
    {
        if (!$this->entitiesC->contains($entityC))
        {
            $this->entitiesC->add($entityC);
            $entityC->setEntityB($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function addEntitiesC($entitiesC)
    {
        foreach ($entitiesC as $entityC)
        {
            $this->addEntityC($entityC);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEntityC(EntityC $entityC)
    {
        if ($this->entitiesC->contains($entityC))
        {
            $this->entitiesC->removeElement($entityC);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEntitiesC($entitiesC)
    {
        foreach ($entitiesC as $entityC)
        {
            $this->removeEntityC($entityC);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Entity C**

```
class EntityC
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityB", inversedBy="entitiesC")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_b_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $entityB;

    public function getEntityB()
    {
        return $this->entityB;
    }

    public function setEntityB(EntityB $entityB)
    {
        $this->entityB = $entityB;
        $entityB->addEntityC($this);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

So, now, assume that we have this data :

```
EntityA [
    EntitiesB [
        EntityB1 [
            EntitiesC [
                EntityC1
                EntityC2
                EntityC3
            ]
        ]
        EntityB2 [
            EntitiesC [
                EntityC4
            ]

        ]
    ]
]
```

That I want is to transfer `EntityC4` to the `EntityB1[EntitieC] collection`.

To achieve that, the process would be :

```
- EntityB2.EntitiesC::removeEntityC(EntityC4)
- EntityB1.EntitiesC::addEntity(EntityC4)
```

But it will not do the trick ... `EntityC4` is removed and not transferred !

So, it works when `orphanRemoval=false` on `EntityB.EntitiesC`, but I want to keep this Doctrine flag.

Is it another way to achieve that properly ?

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the Doctrine documentation [chapter **8.7. Orphan Removal**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal) you can see the following:

> When using the `orphanRemoval=true` option Doctrine makes the assumption that the entities are privately owned and will **NOT** be reused by other entities. If you neglect this assumption your entities will get deleted by Doctrine even if you assigned the orphaned entity to another one.

Seems to me that this this is exactly the mistake you are making in this case.
You simply cannot use `orphanRemoval` in this case.